# Count unique values of a column in all data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, unique, lapply

I have a list of two data frames. Each data frame has a var1 and a var2. I am trying to calculate the count of unique observations of var1 in all data frames. I am able to do this for each individual data frame.

Data frame 1:

```
var1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
var2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
df1 <- data.frame(var1, var2)
df1_count <- length(unique(df1$var1))
```

df1_count gives the correct answer of 5.

Data frame 2:

```
var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
var2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
df2 <- data.frame(var1, var2)
df2_count <- length(unique(df2$var1))
```

df2_count gives the correct answer of 4.

But how do I do this when df1 and df2 are in a list?

```
my_list<-list(df1, df2)
```

I thought it would be as follows:

```
my_list_count <- lapply(my_list, length(unique(my_list$var1)))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any suggestions?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `sapply(my_list, function(x) length(unique(x[, "var1"])))`

Comment: `sapply(my_list, function(x) length(unique(x$var1)))`

Comment: Both work, many thanks! Please allow a follow up question. I would like to use the results as a constant and multiply it with each observation of var2. So, what I am trying to do is: In each data frame, calculate the number of unique values of var1 and multiply this result with each value of var2. How would I go about this?

Comment: It's as simple as `sapply(my_list, function(x) length(unique(x$var1)) * x$var2)`

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!